# PDO query with parameter

Tags: pdo

I used mysql and now i want to update my code to PDO. I have a problem with query:

```
$stmt4 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ore_lavoro WHERE dottore = :dottore AND disponibile = 'si' AND data = :data AND fine >= :fine AND inizio >= '1' AND inizio <= ".$start."");
$stmt4->execute(['dottore' => $dottore_disponibile,'data' => $data_final,'fine' => $end]); 
$count2 = $stmt4->rowCount();
print "There are " .  $count2 . " matching records.";
$data4 = $stmt4->fetchAll();
```

If i i make this query i have this message: "There are 0 matching records."

```
$stmt4 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ore_lavoro WHERE dottore = :dottore AND disponibile = 'si' AND data = :data AND fine >= ".$end." AND inizio >= '1' AND inizio <= ".$start."");
$stmt4->execute(['dottore' => $dottore_disponibile,'data' => $data_final]); 
$count2 = $stmt4->rowCount();
```

If i make this, instead, i recived: "There are 1 matching records" that is the correct answer because in my db i have 1 row with this parameters.
Why? What am I doing wrong
This is my db: https://ibb.co/n6qNXMB

Comment: Obviously, there is nothing visibly wrong with this code, it's the same as in any tutorial. In order to ask a question regarding the data stored in your database, you must provide a [minimal working example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) that clearly demonstrates the problem

Comment: @YourCommonSense i posted my db img, if it is quite.

Comment: Absolutely not. MCVE means a *working* example, i.e. you are posting a code that everyone can copy and paste and run.

Comment: what is the field type for the `fine` field?

Comment: what is the **field type**? varchar, int, text, blob?

Comment: @Your Common Sense fine is int type

Comment: if `fine` is indeed has an **int** type, then both queries should work.

Comment: Look, the only difference is that the second query is like `fine >= 2` and the first one is `fine >= '2'` with 2 being in quotes. but the fact is, Mysql doesn't see any difference, either '2' or 2 should work. You need to check it out again

Comment: @YourCommonSense my "dottore" field is varchar, what i have to change to the code if a field is varchar or text? thanks

Comment: There are no problems with dottore field, as far as I can see

Comment: But for the feature, if i have only varchar field, the pdo statement is similar? Thanks a lot

Comment: PDO statement is the same, no matter the field type.

Comment: As I can see, the problem is in the `fine` column. Am I right? Did you resolve it?

Comment: Not yet, in the night i recreated the database, and this afternoon i'll try again with the query, thanks